# Remove terminal message after kill system call

Tags: c, process, operating-system, system-calls, kill

I am killing a child from the parent using:

```
kill(pid, SIGTERM);
```

It outputs to Terminal

```
Terminated
```

How can "Terminated" not be shown in Terminal?

```
pid_t pid ;
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0){ // pid is process index id in parent process
  wait(NULL); // wait for state changes in child 
  if(execlp(argv[1],argv[1],NULL) == -1){ // argv1 can be either valid or invalid (for example ls or alsjdf)
      char str[128];
      sprintf(str, "./multifork: %s",argv[1]);
      perror(str); 
      kill(pid, SIGINT);
  }
}
```

If `argv[1]` is not a legit system call, I want to exit all programs. Both parent and children, which are created after that.

Comment: could try SIGINT.  I don't recall seeing a message when you kill with CTRL+C...

Comment: YEP.  sending SIGINT(2) kills silently.  sending SIGKILL(9) causes "Killed" to be printed.  You can test for your case using kill -2 <target_pid>

Comment: But it adds a new line when I use SIGINT. Can the \n be removed from output

Comment: @KarinaK the output comes from your **shell**, i.e. `bash` for example. The message exists to tell the user of the shell that the program they were running exited abnormally.

Comment: Now the question is: are you killing the child from parent, *or the parent from the child*

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I added a code snippet to the question.

Comment: The snippet doesn't look too good, why are you trying to kill process 0?

Comment: Hmm...everything in the `if(pid==0)` block only runs in the child process.  That `kill(pid, SIGINT)` tries to kill the process w/pid 0, which probably doesn't exist.  you might want to look at `getppid()` to get the parent process ID.

Comment: that code wouldn't match that behaviour though! also you need to have `(char *)NULL` in `execlp` (you can check from the man pages)`. The `wait(NULL)` in *child* would hang before exec.

Comment: My point is that the `Terminated` / whatever will *only* occur when the *parent* process has been killed with signal. If your child process is killed with signal and parent waits for it, the shell wouldn't print anything.

Comment: Can you try this instead of kill instruction:
sprintf(str, "kill -SIGINT %d >> /dev/null 2>&1",pid);
system(str);

Comment: @Gaston it wrked, post this as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this instead of kill instruction:

```
sprintf(str, "kill -SIGINT %d >> /dev/null 2>&1",pid); 
system(str);
```

system is used to execute the command in shell.
">> /dev/null 2>&1" is redirecting printing to /dev/null, in other words discarding printing of the answer ("terminated").

Comment: And can you explain what it does so that it could be helpful in the future too.

Comment: The way I understand it is:
kill -SIGINT pid == kill(getpid(),SIGINT); // kill parrent; dev/null redirects standard output to /dev/null, which discards it;2>&1 -> redirect STDERR to STDOUT

Comment: There are many articles describing the printing redirect mechanism. One example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/what-does-dev-null-21-mean-in-this-article-of-crontab-basics